# Can we submit a package from patch org to appexchange?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I have released a managed package from a patch org as I have to fix one bug in product, just wanted to get information as I am not sure whether we can submit a package released from a patch org to appExchange!

Please advise.

Comment: I typically just provide the link to the client that needs the patch (or push it). If you wish to list it as the current package release you really should add the fixes to the main package and upload that. As for a patch being the main package on the listing, not sure but it may not be possible..